# jsf / icefaces selectOneMenu autocomplete

Tags: html, icefaces, selectonemenu

I am using ice:selectOneMenu component and want to change the way he work so it will look like this:

when the user click on the letters the list is opened and the first object in the list with this value is shown on the top .

for example when I click 'o' all the value that start with 'o' will be shown , and when I add the letter 'n' all the values that start with 'on' will be on the top .

I know it is possible in java , but is it possible for web application .

right now the component will do it only if the typing is continuous   , if we do a brake between pressing the 'o' and pressing the 'n' it will jump to the values that start with 'n'.

I would love an example to how this could be done . 
I can use Icefaces / JSF2.0 / html 4.0 .

thanks 
Tami

Comment: Can refer here - http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/autocomplete-tutorial.html

Comment: this is not the same , I tried it but it is not good for my bos (:   she want me to let the user open the full list (just like in  ice:selectOneMenu ) and let the user enter letters to specify on what option the focus will be .